# Custom control raiseevent did not fire event (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, controls, custom-controls, raiseevent

I have custom control with n buttons, clicking button will change the variable 'state' and fire the stateChanged event, so in the main form I just put that custom-control and handle program with myCustomControl1_stateChanged sub.

```
Public Class myCustomControl

Private _mstate As Integer = 0

Public Event stateChanged()

Public Property State() As Integer
    Get
        State = _mstate
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _ChangeState(value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Private Sub Buttton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click,
    btnEdit.Click, btnDel.Click, btnSave.Click, btnUndo.Click, btnPrint.Click
    Dim newState As Integer = 0
    If sender Is btnAdd Then newState = 1
    If sender Is btnEdit Then newState = 2
    If _mstate <> newState Then
        _mstate = newState
        RaiseEvent stateChanged()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

but this code did not fire sub myCustomControl1_stateChanged()
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include what the file with `myCustomControl1_stateChanged` in it looks like. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!